# How can I remove a well-like border from input?

Tags: css, html

I wanted to achieve the same effect with `input` element as I can achieve with `contenteditable` attribute. What I have done can be seen in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DB9Mb/1/).

***HTML :***

```
<div class="greenStripe">
    <input placeholder="Title" class='t'/>  
</div>
```

***CSS :***

```
.greenStripe{
    background-color:#13b4ff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; 
}
.greenStripe .t{
    margin: 20px 0 0 10%;
    font-size: 42px;
    background-color:#13b4ff;
}
```

Basically `<input/>` looks almost the same as `contenteditable`, but I have this terrible `border`s. Can I somehow get rid of them with *CSS*?

Comment: `.greenStripe input { border: none; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
input { border-style: none; outline: 0; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DB9Mb/10/)